# how to trigger python code after an event

Tags: python

I want to start some python codes after another software.

This software do some data extractions and gives me periodically some results in CVS file form (weekly). What I want to do is to trigger my Python code to be executed on these file in order to do some functions with them and I want this to be done after every extraction.

I have tried while(1) but it doesn't seem to be efficient.

Is there any Python codes or a software to execute the Python that I can use to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what i get from your question you could call the python script from the software doing the extraction? If you can not do that, you could maybe script a check on the files modified time and call that script every X minutes in crontab?

Comment: yes that s what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch the folder then act on the files creation and/or modify events. Your script can be watching a remote drive on the network if needed.

The following is cut out of working code but I can't confirm it works in this snippet state.  It'll call `HandleNewlyCreated()` for newly created files.

```py
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class WatchPendingHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    ''' Run a handler for every file added to the pending dir

    This class also handles what I call a bug in the watchdog module
    which means that you can get more than one call per real event
    in the watched dir tree.
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        super(WatchPendingHandler, self).__init__()
        # wip is used to avoid bug in watchdog which means multiple calls
        # for one real event.
        # For reference: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/346
        self.wip = []

    def on_created(self, event):
        path = event.src_path
        if event.is_directory:
            logging.debug('WatchPendingHandler() New dir created in pending dir: {}'.format(path))
            return
        if path in self.wip:
            logging.debug('WatchPendingHandler() Dup created event for %s', path)
            return
        self.wip.append(path)
        logging.debug('WatchPendingHandler() New file created in pending dir: {}'.format(path))
        HandleNewlyCreated(path)

    def on_moved(self, event):
        logging.debug('WatchPendingHandler() %s has been moved', event.src_path)
        with contextlib.suppress(ValueError):
            self.wip.remove(event.src_path)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        path = event.src_path
        logging.debug('WatchPendingHandler() %s has been deleted', path)
        with contextlib.suppress(ValueError):
            self.wip.remove(path)

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(WatchPendingHandler(), DIR_PENDING, recursive=True)
observer.start()
logging.info('Watching %s', DIR_PENDING)
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Explanation of `on_created()`:
It will check if the event was for the creation of a directory.  If so it logs the event and then returns/ignores it.  It then checks whether the file created event has previously happened (path in `self.wip`).  If so, it also ignores the event and returns.  Now it can record the event in `self.wip`, log the new event and then call `HandleNewlyCreated()` to process the newly created file.

If the file is moved or deleted, then we need to remove the path from `self.wip` so that the next created event for a new file won't be ignored.

More info here: https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

Comment: Could you explain what on_created function does ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with detail but the short answer is it'll call `HandleNewlyCreated()` only for files and only once when they are created.